# C# open forms with button

Tags: c#, winforms, button, objectdisposedexception

I want to ask this. I have a form this form can control 4 more forms. When i click on the "open form 1" button it is okay but when i clicked "open form 2 " i getting some problem.

my codes like

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Form2 ac = new Form2();
    Form3 ac2 = new Form3();


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ac2.Close();

        ac.Show();

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ac.Close();

        ac2.Show();

    }
```

error tag = System.ObjectDisposedException (BUTTON 1 CLICK AFTER BUTTON 2 CLICK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `Close` a form, the form object gets disposed and hence you wouldn't be able to call `Show` on the disposed object. Read about Form.Close() [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close(v=vs.110).aspx).

> When a form is closed, all resources created within the object are
>   closed and the form is disposed. You can prevent the closing of a form
>   at run time by handling the Closing event and setting the Cancel
>   property of the CancelEventArgs passed as a parameter to your event
>   handler. If the form you are closing is the startup form of your
>   application, your application ends.

You should be using `Hide` method instead of `Close` on clicking the buttons, which will only  hide the form from the user. Modify your functions as follows:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ac2.Hide();

    ac.Show();

}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ac.Hide();

    ac2.Show();

}
```

**OR**

Create new instance of form on button click handlers as follows:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ac2.Close();
    ac2 = null;

    if(ac == null)
    {
       ac = new Form2();
    }

    ac.Show();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ac.Close();
    ac = null;

    if(ac2 == null)
    {
       ac2 = new Form3();
    }

    ac2.Show();
}
```

Comment: I used hide method but I need close();

Comment: please check the updated answer. You might have to create form instance on button clicks (if it was previously closed)

Comment: YOU ARE BEST.!!

Comment: Glad that I could help..:) Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

If anybody wants to use more forms can use that code block...

```
 private void ButtonDashboard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comeuser.Close();
        comeuser = null;

        comereports.Close();
        comereports = null;

        comeabout.Close();
        comeabout = null;



        if (comedash == null)
        {
            comedash = new DashBoard();
        }


            comedash.TopLevel = false;
            comedash.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            comedash.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            comedash.Show();
            MainEventPanel.Controls.Add(comedash);












        ButtonDashboard.Textcolor = Color.FromArgb(222, 120, 53);
        ButtonUser.Textcolor = Color.Gainsboro;
        ButtonReports.Textcolor = Color.Gainsboro;
        ButtonAbout.Textcolor = Color.Gainsboro;
        HeaderMain.Text = "Dashboard";













    }
private void ButtonUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (comedash != null)
        {
            comedash.Close();

        }

        if (comereports!=null)
        {
            comereports.Close();

        }

        comereports = null;


        if (comeabout != null)
        {
            comeabout.Close();

        }

        comeabout = null;

        if (comeuser==null)
        {
            comeuser = new UserControl();
        }





            comeuser.TopLevel = false;
            comeuser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            comeuser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            comeuser.Show();
            MainEventPanel.Controls.Add(comeuser);
















        ButtonUser.Textcolor = Color.FromArgb(222, 120, 53);
        ButtonDashboard.Textcolor = Color.Gainsboro;
        ButtonReports.Textcolor = Color.Gainsboro;
        ButtonAbout.Textcolor = Color.Gainsboro;
        HeaderMain.Text = "User Control";










    }
    private void ButtonReports_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        comedash.Close();
        comedash = null;

        comeuser.Close();
        comeuser = null;

        comeabout.Close();
        comeabout = null;

        if (comeabout==null)
        {
            comeabout = new About();

        }



        comereports.TopLevel = false;
        comereports.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        comereports.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        comereports.Show();
        MainEventPanel.Controls.Add(comereports);

        ButtonReports.Textcolor = Color.FromArgb(222, 120, 53);
        ButtonUser.Textcolor = Color.Gainsboro;
        ButtonDashboard.Textcolor = Color.Gainsboro;
        ButtonAbout.Textcolor = Color.Gainsboro;

        HeaderMain.Text = "Reports";
    }
```